Firebase App Check Debug Token not showing on Flutter run
I'm trying to get App Check to work in my Flutter application (Android).
I followed the step by step configuration in the documentation in this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers.
But when I do the procedure to get the Debug Token (from this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider), it is not printed in the terminal when I run the app using the flutter run command.
I tried running the application to see if the Debug Token was printed with the App Check registered and not registered in the Firebase apps, and also with the APIs of the services applied and not applied. In neither case was the Debug Token printed.
Here's the relevant part of my pubspec.yaml file:
environment:
  sdk: ^3.6.0

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: ^5.6.0
  cloud_functions: ^5.1.5
  firebase_app_check: ^0.3.1+7
  firebase_auth: ^5.3.4
  firebase_core: ^3.9.0
  firebase_storage: ^12.3.7

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^5.0.0

